# I purchased a spy pen voice recorder. It records in .wav extension. I have Windows 11. It does not recognize .wav, but does play .MP3 and .MP4

Tags: audio

I purchased a spy pen voice recorder.  It records in .wav extension.  I have Windows 11.  It does not recognize .wav but does play .MP3 and .MP4

Comment: WAV files are native to Windows; the format was invented by Microsoft [& IBM] - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV What error do you get?

Comment: As this is a Q&A site, it will be good if you asked an explicit *question*. Note "why?", "how can I make Windows play the files?" and "how can I check if the files are valid `.wav`s?" are not equivalent, they require different answers. Each of these examples (or something else) may be your question. Please [edit] and don't let us guess what your question really is.

Answer (score 2):

Even a post on the Microsoft support website recommends that you use **VLC player**

> Windows 11 will not play mp3 or wav files consistently.  Sometimes it will and sometimes (mostly) it won't.  Occasionally it will work if I reboot.   Windows 11 is updated.   The error code I'm getting for both of these files is:
>
> We can't open x file.  It uses unsupported encoding settings 0X80040154
>
> Hi, I'm Elise, and I'd be happy to help with your issue.
>
> Could you try download and install VLC player and see if this allows you to play the files?

From [answers.microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-will-not-play-mp3-or-wav-files/b38fe83a-c37e-455f-ab40-a65b4e355e17)

[Download VLC Here](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)